# How to keep the same dict value while filling the nans in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, fillna

Assume we have the dict having the median values of the features:
`infereddict =  {sepalwidth : -0.03999432052319804, sepalheight :-0.08741807979521529,  petalwitdh: -0.049475134763957505}`

while we fill the nans in datafarame with the dict , it changes the value and gives below output
`sepalwidth -3.999432e-02     sepalheight -8.741808e-02    petalwitdh -4.947513e-02`

Seems its ignoring the zeros, I need the exact same values from dict to fill the nans, how can we get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is displaying the numbers in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). The values are equal to each other, it's just a different way of displaying numbers.

Some examples of comparing the two and converting between two formats

```
>>> # You can directly check that they're equal to each other
>>> -0.039994 == -3.9994e-2
True
>>> # Type in a number in scientific notation to see its decimal counterpart
>>> -8.741808e-02
-0.08741808
>>> # Use f-strings and ':e' to view a decimal in scientific notation format
>>> f"{-0.04947513:e}"
-4.947513e-02
```